# Are air particles massless?

Tags: thermodynamics, mass, atmospheric-science, air, gas

so as the question suggests, I wanna know whether an air particle has mass or no. Thank you!

Comment: What is *air particle*? Air consists of Nitrogen oxygen and other gases - they are not massless.

Answer (score 5):

Air is composed of gases mainly nitrogen and oxygen, what are not massless.
And if you refer to whether air has weight, it does have weight.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had a big bag full of water. It would be very heavy. The same bag underwater would weight nothing. Water sits there, whether a bag surrounds it or not.

So fish are much less aware than we are of how much water weighs. To them it is everywhere, but it just sits there. You don't have to make any effort to hold it up.

We are like fish that live in air. Air has a surprising amount of weight in a vacuum, but we are unaware of it.

Water and air have weight because the both have mass. Mass is a measure of how much matter is there. Weight is a measure of how hard gravity pulls on it.

You can feel that water has mass by standing in a current. Moving water has momentum. It pushes on you.

Likewise, a wind pushes on you. It is evidence that air has mass.

The density of air is about $1000$ times less than water. A cubic meter of air has a mass of $1000$ kg, or a metric ton. A cubic meter of air has a mass of $1$ kg. This is a significant mass. It would hurt if you dropped a $1$ kg rock on your toe.

In English units, this roughly translates to $1$ cubic yard of water weighs about a ton, while that much air weighs (in vacuum) a couple pounds.

If you think about the volume of air in your house, you can figure out that you would have trouble lifting that much mass, if you didn't live surrounded by air.